# ejs compilation error in node.js express app

Tags: node.js, ejs

I'm trying to include `header.ejs` and `footer.ejs` file with my `home.ejs` file.

A `home.ejs` file is located in views folder and the others are located in `views/partials`.

While including the file I get the error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in D:\wamp64\www\Training\node_pug\views\home.ejs while compiling ejs

I am a beginner in `nodejs`.

**header.ejs**

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
 <html>
     <head>
         <title>
             <link rel="stylesheet" hreff="app.css">
         </title>
     </head>
 <body>
```

**footer.ejs**

```
</body>
</html>
```

**service.js**

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });
app.use(express.static('public'));

var session = require('express-session');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
const ejsLint = require('ejs-lint');

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.render('login');
});

app.get('/home', function(request, response) {
  response.render('home');
});  

app.post('/auth', urlencodedParser,function(request, response) {
  var username = request.body.username;
  var password = request.body.password;
    if(username == 'admin')
    {       
       //response.redirect('ejs/home');
       response.render('home');    
    }else{
      response.render('login');
    }
  });

var server = app.listen(8080,function(){
  console.log('server is running...');
});
```

**home.ejs**

```html
<% include partials/header %>
<h1>welcome</h1>
<% include partials/footer %>
```

Comment: Review Edit: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the your code wrap - indents in particular, separated code by blocks, I also updated the description of your question, please consider grammar.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://github.com/mde/ejs): The recommended way to include a file is as below:

```
<%- include('partials/header') %>
 <h1>welcome</h1>
<%- include('partials/footer') %>
```

The docs state that

> NOTE: Include preprocessor directives (<% include user/show %>) are not supported in v3.0+.

You are probably using a v3.0+ version of EJS hence the error you are experiencing. The snippet above should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express 4.X you should probably use this syntax in your `home.ejs`.

```
<%- include partials/header.ejs %>
 <h1>welcome</h1>
<%- include partials/footer.ejs %>
```